# How do I set the content length when downloading a files in Grails

Tags: grails

I have a method in my controller that allows to download the file that was uploaded. I am trying to have the Content-Length header be added to the download method so download progress bars work.

Problem is mine is not working which is `response.setContentLength("${documentInstance.fileSize}")`

I am getting error that file not found. If it take off this method the download will work

Here is the method

```
def download(long id) {
    Document documentInstance = Document.get(id)
    if ( documentInstance == null) {
        flash.message = "Document not found."
        redirect (action:'list')
    } else {
        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM")
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=\"${documentInstance.filename}\"")
        response.setContentLength("${documentInstance.fileSize}")
        def file = new File(documentInstance.fullPath)
        def fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
        def outputStream = response.getOutputStream()
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int len;
        while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()
        fileInputStream.close()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set it has a Header parameter:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", "${bytes.length}")
```

Also, you might want to disable rendering of the view after you've streamed the file.

```
webRequest.renderView = false
```